# usb boot: what file am I supposed to select on the bootable stick?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, dell, live-usb

I have a problem setting up a USB boot on a Dell Precision 7560 laptop (brand new!). It was delivered with Windows preinstalled, and Dell BIOS ref. 1.80. The goal is to enable a double-boot system (20.04+MS Win), grub-driven.

I have already done this in the past, but seems that things got a bit more complicated today. Some steps I have already made:

- Secure boot has been correctly disabled.
- I have setup a bootable USB drive, built with unetbootin from a 20.04 desktop ISO. I have tested it on a VirtualBox VM: works fine.

When I did configure that previously (years ago...), all you had to do was to select the "USB boot" in the Bios. But on this machine, there was no default USB boot in the BIOS, so I had to add a new option.
When doing so, a dialog requests to select, first, a drive/file system (see fig below), second, a file!

My question is simple: 
**What is the file that must be selected?** (`$ find . | wc -l` returns 1050 files on that drive...)

I have tried `ldlinux.sys` (sounded good ;-) and several others, failed to boot every time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have a Dell Precision m4800 laptop, pretty old but still going strong with an i7 CPU, and a Dell Latitude 3520, pretty new, but with a low-end i3 CPU. Both are happy booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from USB both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode). Is your problem to boot from a live USB drive, or from an installed Ubuntu system (installed in a USB drive)? Both are possible, (also installed systems). Please describe in detail what you have and what you want (how far things work until they fail), and also the version number of the computer and the graphics chip.

Comment: thanks for comment. I added the Dell reference. Can't really say more than... does not boot once I select (randomly) a file on the USB FS and try to boot! Maybe you know what is the first file that gets loaded?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the computer does not boot from the USB boot drive (created by Unetbootin). My first suggestion is to use the newest version Ubuntu *22.04* LTS (not 20.04) and a *cloning tool* to create the USB boot drive. The age or your computer's UEFI/BIOS system should be similar to that of my Latitude 3520, which is happy to boot from such a drive. There may be a problem if you have nvidia graphics, that you need to add the boot option `nomodeset` in the grub menu (can be done manually during boot) in order for the graphical desktop environment to work.

Comment: If you have only Windows, I suggest that you use **Rufus and select 'dd-mode'** to make it clone from the iso file to the USB drive. If you have Ubuntu in another computer, you can use the **Startup Disk Creator** or install and use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: Your Dell BIOS version is 1.80 and mine 1.17.4 and it was updated recently to be up to date in the 3520 computer, so the BIOSes might be too different for the results in my 3520 to 'promise' similar results in your computer, but there is still hope.

Comment: For UEFI boot of live installer, you should not have to change any UEFI settings. Those would be for once system is installed & you then want UEFI boot. In F12 you should have two boot options, one clearly UEFI as UEFI:xxx where xxx is name or label of flash drive. If you also have just xxx that would be a BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot which you do not want. Some tools to create live installer flash drives may make either only UEFI or only BIOS bootable versions. Most make a flash drive that can be booted either way, so you have to choose in UEFI boot.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, but I think I did solve the issue: the solution was to select the "UEFI general UDisk" in the boot sequence. I'll post an answer. BTW, for future readers, it is perfectly fine to install a previous release, as long as it is LTS (20.04 or 18.04 as of today). And Unetbootin works fine too.

Comment: The reasons for installing a previous release are multiple, but mostly (in my case) due to potential latency in support for latest Ubuntu with some tools (Ros to name it).

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer to my question:

There is no need to create a new "USB" boot entry in the boot sequence list. The solution is to select **UEFI general UDisk** in the boot sequence, shown on above figure (fourth line). Then, boot on USB stick (and whole install process) is eventless.

Didn't know, but UDisk seems to mean "UDISK is a hard drive in USB form" ([source](https://www.getflashmemory.info/whats-the-difference-between-usb-and-udisk/)).

Although that term is not today referenced on the [WP UEFI page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface).

Comment: +1+1; thanks for sharing your solution :-)